# Python, преобразование полезной нагрузки в словарь или json

Tags: python, сервер, http

Http server на питоне получает строку вида *param1=one&param2=two* через POST. Можно ли преобразовать её в словарь или в json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
import json

parse_qs('param1=one&param2=two')
# {'param1': ['one'], 'param2': ['two']}
parse_qsl('param1=one&param2=two')
# [('param1', 'one'), ('param2', 'two')]

json.dumps(parse_qs('param1=one&param2=two'))
# '{"param1": ["one"], "param2": ["two"]}'
```